# How do I integrate event-drive architectures between AWS and Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cross-platform, azureservicebus, aws-event-bridge

I need to extend an event-driven architecture across a multi-cloud environment. AWS Eventbridge is the present bus. I need to use functions in Azure. I'm considering the following:

1. AWS Eventbridge - direct connection to Azure Service Bus. Is this possible? Has anyone done it? If so, how?
2. Azure Functions directly connecting to AWS Eventbridge and using the Azure funtions to drive Azure functionality.

Thoughts on these two approaches? or other options?